# How to configure php.ini to use gmail as mail server

Tags: smtp, gmail, wamp, php

I want to learn yii as my first framework. And I'm trying to make the contact form work. But I got this error:
[image]

I've already configured php.ini file from:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0
```

And changed the default to these values:

```
 [mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = ssl:smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 23

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com
```

I've seen from here that gmail doesn't use port 25, which is the default in the php.ini. So I used 23. And also opened that port in the windows 7 firewall. Via inbound rules.

Then I also edited the main config in my yii application, to match the email that I'm using:

```
// application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'myemail@gmail.com',
    ),
);
```

Finally, I restarted wampserver. Then cleared all my browsing data. Why then to I still see that its pointing out port 25 in the error. Have I miss something? Please help.

Comment: port 25 and 23 are both wrong. Furthermore gmail only accepts smtp after authorisation. So somewhere you also have to enter your username and password. See http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287 I don't know whether yii is able to send mail using TLS or SSL

Comment: If you're using SSL, enter 465.
If you're using TLS, enter 587.

Answer (score 4):

Heres a simple python script which could allow you to run a mail server on localhost, you dont have to change anything. Sorry if im a bit late.

```
import smtpd

import smtplib

import asyncore

class SMTPServer(smtpd.SMTPServer):

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        print "Running fake smtp server on port 25"
        smtpd.SMTPServer.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def process_message(*args, **kwargs):
        to = args[3][0]
        msg = args[4]
        gmail_user = 'yourgmailhere'
        gmail_pwd = 'yourgmailpassword'
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
        smtpserver.ehlo()
        smtpserver.starttls()
        smtpserver.ehlo
        smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
        smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
        print 'sent to '+to
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    smtp_server = SMTPServer(('localhost', 25), None)
    try:
        asyncore.loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        smtp_server.close()

#end of code
```

Note: I used args[3][0] and args[4] as to address and message as the args sent by my php mail() corresponded to an array of args[3][0] as receipent email

Comment: ```process_message``` not invoked after I'm trying to send via ```mail()``` in php

Comment: This is outside the scope of the question stop fishing for reps

Comment: OMG! server fake it works fine, i create file python an runing. And in the php.ini file to default do not fix anything. And I got the email sent.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

If you open the `php.ini` file in WAMP, you will find these two lines:

```
smtp_server
smtp_port
```

Add the server and port number for your host (you may need to contact them for details)

The following two lines don't exist by default:

```
auth_username
auth_password
```

So you will need to add them to be able to send mail from a server that requires authentication. So an example may be:

```
smtp_server = mail.example.com
smtp_port = 25
auth_username = example_username@example.com
auth_password = example_password
```

ps: you should not use your personal mail here. for an obvious reason.

Comment: thank you very much for formatting..    As i am new i didn't know the rules. and markdown style.. 
 @DACrosby

Answer (score 0):

If using WAMP, the php.ini to be configured is present in the wamp/bin/apache/Apache_x_y/bin folder

where _x_y is related to the version of the Apache build used by your wamp installation

Answer (score 0):

1. uncomment extension=php_openssl.dll at php.ini in WAMP server ("D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini")
2. In the file "D:\wamp\www\mantisbt-1.2.15\config_inc.php"

```
    # --- Email Configuration ---

    $g_phpMailer_method = PHPMAILER_METHOD_SMTP; 
    $g_smtp_host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $g_smtp_connection_mode = 'ssl';
    $g_smtp_port = 465;
    $g_smtp_username        = 'yourmail@gmail.com'; 
    $g_smtp_password        = 'yourpwd';
    $g_enable_email_notification = ON;
    $g_log_level = LOG_EMAIL | LOG_EMAIL_RECIPIENT;
    $g_log_destination = 'file:/tmp/log/mantisbt.log';  
    $g_administrator_email  = 'administrator@example.com';
    $g_webmaster_email      = 'webmaster@example.com';
    $g_from_email           = 'noreply@example.com';
    $g_return_path_email    = 'admin@example.com';  
    $g_from_name            = 'Mantis Bug Tracker';
    $g_email_receive_own    = OFF;
    $g_email_send_using_cronjob = OFF;
```