# sending email from php using yahoo smtp

Tags: php

I am tired on finding out solutions on how to configure php ini to send email using yahho or gmail. When I use the mil function it doesn't gives me any error but I don't receive the mail also.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095289/how-to-configure-php-ini-to-use-gmail-as-mail-server

Comment: I like PHPMailer.  You can see how to use it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8629554/1477388 which is a solution for gmail smtp, but you can use it for yahoo smtp, too.  You can download it here http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php4/0.90/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can config the section '[mail function]' in php.ini.
And set SMTP to your SMTP Server, and smtp_port set to 25 which is the standard port used for SMTP connections.

In gmail, the setting is like below:

> SMTP: smtp.gmail.com
>
> Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587
>
> Port for SSL: 465

Hope this help you.

Comment: hey Thanks..what is this Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587?? Where can I find that?

Comment: I think you can try the following code, and you'll get know what I mean.
$mail= new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8"; 
$mail->Username = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "your password";